# Wicked Winding Words!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, visual, word-property, open-ended

[image: WORDS]

> ***What is the highest number $n$ of $n$-letter words can you find that share this property? i.e. highest number $n$ that you can find (not found on any other sites).***

I will accept the answer with the highest number $n$. So if $n=5$ is the highest out of the answers at a given moment (with a solution different to above), then I will accept the answer with that particular solution. Then, if an answer reveals a solution for $n=6$, I will then accept that since $6>5$.

Good luck, and have fun!

<sub>Also, I wonder if one can find a solution where all the given words rhyme, excusing one column that is.</sub>

---

**P.S.**

I have used the tag [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) because I have not officially stated the sharing property of the words shown above, but I am certain it is obvious; I have also used the tag [word-problem](/questions/tagged/word-problem) for clear reasons that disagree with the purpose of using such a tag, however; and I am not fully certain if it is appropriate to include the tag [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay).

Comment: ***My friend sent me this picture of these arranged words he found on the internet. Anybody know where it's from?***

Comment: This is called a word square. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square

Comment: I removed the word-problem tag because, as you say, this question does not fit the description of that tag.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan $\diamondsuit@ okay, that is understandable. Thanks you :)

Comment: What counts as a word, exactly?

Comment: @Deusovi $\diamondsuit$ just any regular word; a word that can be found in the dictionary, and when you type it on this site (or in a document), it does not have a red scribbled/dotted line underneath.

Comment: "The dictionary"? Which dictionary? Different dictionaries have different words. Some have proper nouns, and some do not. Some allow phrases, and some do not. Do hyphenated words count as words? What about loanwords?

Comment: @Deusovi $\diamondsuit$ ahh, yes I didn't consider those. Hyphenated words do not count, and these words must be found in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/). I have no idea what loanwords are, but after doing some research, I don't think so. Just English words (at least, for the time being). I suppose names may also be included, but only notable ones (e.g. Moses). Phrases also do not count; it is strictly words.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Open ended questions are now off topic and there is also no definition of what is a valid word

Comment: Using [YAWL](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl) as the word list is a good option since it doesn't change. Additionally, it's not clear what is meant by "*that share this property*", clarifying that is sure to help reception. Looks fun!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the property we are meant to notice is simply

> that the words form a [word square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square) -- i.e., when they are written as shown we can read the same words horizontally and vertically --

it is well known to those who know such things that

> there are plenty of 9x9 word squares but no one has yet constructed a satisfactory 10x10 one using things that are definitely English words. (My guess is that there is none.)

Here is

> an example of a 9x9 square, taken from the Wikipedia page linked above:
>  `A C H A L A S I A`
>  `C R E N I D E N S`
>  `H E X A N D R I C`
>  `A N A B O L I T E`
>  `L I N O L E N I N`
>  `A D D L E H E A D`
>  `S E R I N E T T E`
>  `I N I T I A T O R`
>  `A S C E N D E R S`

Comment: I have edited the question to ask for word squares **not** used from other sites. I did not realise such puzzles were an official thing. I apologise for that.